# Abaqus read input file very slow for many materials

Tags: abaqus

EDIT*: After all it turned out that this is not causing the slow import. Nevertheless the answer given explains a better way to implement different densities with one material. So I'll let the question exist. (Slow import was caused by running the scripts from the abaqus PDE and not using 'Run script' from the file menu. special thanks to droooze for finding the problem)

I'm trying to optimize the porosity distribution of a certain material. Therefor I'm performing abaqus FEA simulations with +-500 different materials in one part. The simulation itself only takes about 40 seconds, but reading the input file takes more than 3 minutes. (I used a python script to generate the inp file)

I'm using these commands to generate my materials in the input file:

```
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET = ES_Implant_MAT0 ,MATERIAL=Implant_material0
*ELSET, ELSET=ES_Implant_MAT336
6,52,356,376,782,1793,1954,1984,3072
*MATERIAL, NAME = Implant_material0
*DENSITY
4.43
*ELASTIC
110000, 0.3
```

Any idea why this is so slow and is there a more efficient way to do this to reduce the load input file time?

Comment: Are you sure that this is what's making it slow?

Comment: Sorry turns out you're right after all. It's not the materials :(. When I use the python command to import the input file as a model it's extremely slow. When I do it manually in the GUI it's a matter of seconds. I use: model = mdb.ModelFromInputFile(name=model_name, inputFileName=inp_file_path) Any ideas? Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that when you're importing the .inp in the GUI it's a matter of seconds, but running `mdb.ModelFromInputFile` takes minutes? That doesn't sound right - File > Import > Model from .inp runs the command `mdb.ModelFromInputFile`, which you can confirm by checking the `abaqus.rpy` file in your working directory. Maybe you mean that you're opening a `.cae` file?

Comment: No, that's what I meant. I already checked the .rpy file and indeed. It's that exact line of code that is executed. Let me show you with a video: https://youtu.be/4Wzzq29ftPA I don't know what to do anymore, any tips?

Comment: Have you tried running the command outside of the PDE? That interface is only for debugging - normally you'd run scripts via File -> Run Script, or plain commands just in the command window ("Kernel Command Line Interface") on the bottom.

Comment: Yes!!!!!! It's the debugger :D Thank you so much!!! You have no idea how much time you're saving me!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ~500 materials are all of the same kind (e.g. all linear elastic isotropic mass density), then you can collapse it all into one material then define a distribution table which distributes these materials directly onto the instance element label.

Syntax:

(somewhere in the `Part` definition, under `section`)

```
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET = ES_Implant_MAT0 ,MATERIAL=Implant_material0
```

(somewhere in the `Assembly` definition; `part=` should reference the name of the part above)

```
**  
**
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=myinstance, part=mypart
*End Instance
**  
*Elset, elset=ES_Implant_MAT0, instance=myinstance
1,2,...
```

(somewhere in the `Materials` definition; see Abaqus Keywords Reference Guide for the keywords `*DISTRIBUTION TABLE` and `*DISTRIBUTION`)

```
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*DISTRIBUTION TABLE, NAME=IMPLANT_MATERIAL0_ELASTIC_TABLE
         MODULUS,RATIO
*DISTRIBUTION, NAME=Implant_material0_elastic, LOCATION=element, TABLE=IMPLANT_MATERIAL0_ELASTIC_TABLE
        ,110000,0.3 # First line is some default value
myinstance.1,110000,0.3 # syntax: instance name [dot] instance element label
myinstance.2,110000,0.3 # these elements currently use the material properties assigned to `ELSET = ES_Implant_MAT0`. You can define the material properties belonging to other element sets in this same table, making sure you reference the element label correctly.
...
*DISTRIBUTION TABLE, NAME=IMPLANT_MATERIAL0_DENSITY_TABLE
         DENSITY
*DISTRIBUTION, NAME=Implant_material0_density, LOCATION=element, TABLE=IMPLANT_MATERIAL0_DENSITY_TABLE
        ,4.43 # Default value
myinstance.1,4.43
myinstance.2,4.43
...
*Material, name=Implant_material0
*Elastic
 Implant_material0_elastic # Distribution name
*Density
 Implant_material0_density # Distribution name
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think that this will improve the speed? And would it be possible to plot the different 'materials' according to the rainbow spectrum?

Comment: @ThaNoob sorry, I don't know if it'll improve the speed in your case. I use this method to assign 27,000 different materials to 27,000 different elements and it seems to process within seconds. As for plotting different materials, are you talking about plotting it like [the answer I gave here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509158/abaqus-visualize-density/49533359#49533359)?

Comment: I'm just talking about 500 materials, so I guess that should do the trick :). And indeed, that was actually also my post, I found a solution for it myself (be it a bit a workaround) but that's based on having different materials, so I won't be able to use it anymore. So again your help will be useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ThaNoob your models might have other complex features that you didn't mention in the question, so I don't really know what the bottleneck for the I/O is. BTW, if you want to visualise density in the `fieldOutput` and employ the distribution table method here, most of that answer I gave for the visualisation won't help you much - you'll have to use C++ scripting to pull the materials from the .odb or pull the material properties and element labels from the .inp file and construct the `fieldOutput` data from that.

Comment: see my comment on the initial question. You were right, it's not the materials.